# How to get the data

Tags: java, integer, checksum

The user has to enter 9 integers. The sum of the integers is calculated by "ckSum" in the code. According to the nine integers the user enters, if the "cksum" is equal to 10 then the output should be ISBN number with X. IF not then the output should be , the ISBN number and the value of the cksum. For example, if you enter 013031997 , and ckSum would be 10 then the final result should be 013031997X.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class mendfa {
    public static void main(String[] args ){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the ten numbers");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    int number9 = number%10;
    number = number/10;
    int number8 = number%10;
    number = number/10;
    int number7 = number%10;
    number = number/10;
    int number6 = number%10;
    number = number/10;
    int number5 = number%10;
    number = number/10;
    int number4 = number%10;
    number = number/10;
    int number3 = number%10;
    number = number/10;
    int number2 = number%10;
    number = number/10;
    int number1 = number%    10;

    double ckSum = (number1 * 1 + number2 *2 +number3 * 3 +number4 * 4 +number5*5 +number6 * 6 +number7 * 7 + number8 * 8 +number9 * 9)%11;

    if (ckSum == 10){
    System.out.println("The ISBN 10 number is " + number + "X");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The ISBN 10 number is " + number + ckSum);
        }



}
}
```

Comment: Why don't use an array? It will simplify the code a lot.

Comment: what is your question? please do specify what problem you are encountering. One more thing all class name should start with a capital letter.

Comment: What's your question? And search about for loops and arrays to simplify your life.

Comment: I think you forgot the question mark.

Comment: your ckSum will always be an integer (between 0 and 11) .. why use double??

Comment: What is the problem you are facing.

Comment: Why not you are using array and loop to minimize your lines of code.

Comment: Your code seems to have bug. I just ran it and gave input as 0121111111 and it returned 13 as answer where as answer is 10 so the
number = number/10; gives one for first digit instead of 0. Is that the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class mendfa {
    public static void main(String[] args ){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the ten numbers");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int a,sum;
    a= 0;
    int ckSum = 0;
    int tempNum = number;
    while(number!=0)
    {
        a=number%10;
        number=number/10;
        ckSum=ckSum+a;
    }

    if (ckSum == 10){
    System.out.println("The ISBN 10 number is " + tempNum + "X");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The ISBN 10 number is " + tempNum + ckSum);
        }



}
}
```